# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am brand-new to web development and RoR - an uber-noob! - and I'm taking an online RoR course via lynda.com.  Excited to join the StackOverflow community, and would really appreciate some help with a roadblock.

MySQL and localhost were working fine for several weeks as I set up my rudimentary app and successfully ran some migrations, but today I am getting this MySQL error when I launch my rails server and view on http://localhost:3000/ in my browser:

Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)):

I don't think I've changed anything relevant in my environment, so I wonder if I need to update gems or something simple like that?

I've hunted around on Google and StackOverflow for a couple hours now and still can't figure out what went wrong here and how to fix it.  Other solutions seem to relate to new set-ups as opposed to a working set-up that inexplicably breaks.

Here's some context:

---

From my config/database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password: XXXXXXXXX
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

---

I saved a command line from a couple weeks ago when MySQL and localhost were working fine:

```
Last login: Mon Aug 15 21:34:23 on ttys000
sdemessieres$ cd sites/simple_cms
sdemessieres$ pwd
/Users/sdemessieres/sites/simple_cms
sdemessieres$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-08-22 22:28:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-08-22 22:28:01] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12) [universal-darwin10.0]
[2011-08-22 22:28:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=66952 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Aug 22 22:28:20 -0400 2011
  Processing by DemoController#index as HTML
```

etc... (worked fine from here)

---

But then today I tried the same commands and receive the error:

```
Last login: Mon Sep  5 12:13:22 on ttys000
sdemessieres$ cd sites/simple_cms
sdemessieres$ pwd
/Users/sdemessieres/sites/simple_cms
sdemessieres$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-09-05 12:33:09] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-09-05 12:33:09] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12) [universal-darwin10.0]
[2011-09-05 12:33:09] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11027 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Sep 05 12:33:41 -0400 2011

Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)):


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.7ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (6.3ms)
```

---

So I went back to the database notes from my training and tried connecting to MySQL from my command line which had worked before but no longer:

```
sdemessieres$ pwd
/Users/sdemessieres/sites/simple_cms
sdemessieres$ which mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
sdemessieres$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.13, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1
sdemessieres$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
sdemessieres$
```

---

One StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732213/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket) gave me this clue but it only seems to reinforce that my set up is correct.

```
sdemessieres$ mysql_config |grep -- --socket
        --socket         [/tmp/mysql.sock]
```

---

As I said, I am a total beginner so any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This question is somewhat dated, but it I came across it while researching a similar issue.  Confirming the socket location and name with the `mysql_config` command was instrumental in resolving my problem.

I was getting the same error and had adjusted the socket entry path in `config/database.yml` to match where I found the `.sock` file.

However beyond the path change, the socket entry in my `database.yml` file referred to `"mysql.sock"`, as do most of the discussions related to this issue during my search.

The output of `mysql_config` was slightly different.  It revealed that the file name was `"mysqld.sock"`...notice the **'d'**, not `mysql.sock`.  I missed it because I was focussing on the path.

The `mysql` installation is on a server only VPS, no client, which may explain the difference in the socket file name.

Comment: That was helpful. It feels like a newbie mistake, but yes, you may easily miss to check the *d* in the path to the `mysqld.sock` file...

Answer (score 1):

Update: I tried again today without having changed anything at all, and it worked fine.  Go figure.  Wish I knew what happened, though.

Comment: Please edit your own question. Don't answer your self as an edit!!

Comment: @Mr.DDD While I agree on the principle, this is also a self-answer of the question, which I'd dub as "valid"-ish. In this case however, I'd simply delete the question.

Comment: I wouldn't delete the question. The answer may be helpful for others who might realize that if they wait for a bit and run the command again, it'll work.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. It seems like it would be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I run on the same error and for me the both socket information has shown `mysqld`.
I had two sessions defined in mysql client. I resolved my problem by deleting one session definition and leaving only `localhost`. After deleting and re-running the application, the connection worked.

I don't know how it is connected to one another, but it worked, so it might work for someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

rename CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL to DATABASE_URL in heroku configs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and installing mysql again (from the official website) fixed the problem.