# Missing mysql.sock for RoR app on OS X Lion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion

I use two OS X machines to develop my Ruby on Rails application. My desktop works fine, and my laptop was working fine until a few days ago when I got this error when the local server was running on pageload:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I get the same error when I try to run mysql from terminal.

I checked a few other threads, but none of their solutions helped my problem:

[Ruby on Rails 3 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499035/ruby-on-rails-3-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-s)

[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732213/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket)

The last link the guy seems to be having the exact same problem as I do, but the answer on that page didn't help me since I can't run mysql. I keep seeing this problem online where people fixed it because their .sock file was in the wrong location so I ran

```
$ ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp
```

to try to create an alias but it looks like mysql.sock doesn't exist in either place. When I tried running:

```
$ mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

I got this error:

```
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Lastly, I turned on invisible files and went looking around my computer, and couldn't find a mysql.sock file or mysql folder in any of the above directories. Once again, mysql WAS working fine on this computer a week ago, and has now inexplicably stopped working for some reason.

How do I restore or recreate my .sock file for this computer?

Comment: have you tried running mysqld?

Comment: Yeah, here's the output: https://gist.github.com/3068400

Comment: can you post the output of `ps aux | grep mysql` and `which mysql` here? It may be you are running 2 mysql servers in different places.

Comment: You might be onto something with this. https://gist.github.com/3069120  I recently had to change my computer's name on my office's network and that looks like it changed up some file paths in mysql too. Note "Old-Computer-Name" and "New-Computer-Name" in the gist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have installed mysql using homebrew before. Note that you have your mysqld already running at

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.24/bin/mysqld
```

However you current mysql command link to

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

instead, it should be

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.24/bin/mysql
```

You can try add alias to your bashrc pointing to the correct command.

Try kill all other mysqld_safe process before running `mysql` in a new window. It should read the correct mysql sock file now.

Comment: That sounds awesome, what commands do I run to accomplish this? Sorry I am a mysql newbie.

Comment: open `~/.bashrc` add `alias mysql="/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.24/bin/mysql"` at last line. and open new terminal to run `mysql`

Comment: Weird I don't have `~/.bashrc` at all. I have `~/.bash_history` and `~/.bash_profile` Any reason why I wouldn't have this file, or why it wouldn't be in my home directory?

Comment: No good, I tried it in `/etc/bashrc` and I tried creating `~/.bashrc` with only that line in it but when I open a new Terminal window it still gives me `ERROR 2002 (HY000)`, etc.

Comment: try restart your machine and make sure mysqld is running.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be the specified socket path in your Gemfile might be wrong.

First, to find your socket file:

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

For me, this gives:

```
| socket  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Then, add this line `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`  to your config/database.yml in the socket field. See the below examples

**Example:**     `socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

## Development Mode

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock #  this line
```

## Production Mode

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  #  this line
```

## Test Mode

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  #  this line
```